# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 in my "Remove" jFrame Database project

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, indexoutofboundsexception

I have this persistent error that seems impossible to fix. Basically, the "Remove" jButton removes a Row that is elected in my jTable. Not only that, this jTable is connected to my database. So the function of my jButton should remove the Data from my Data Table and then repaint the Table. But everytime i clicked the button this error shows up. What is wrong w/ my code?

public class:

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

String a;
String Price;
String Stock;
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
        jTable_products.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                int selectedRow = jTable_products.getSelectedRow();
                a = (String) jTable_products.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0);
                 Price=String.valueOf(jTable_products.getValueAt(selectedRow, 1));
                  Stock=String.valueOf(jTable_products.getValueAt(selectedRow, 2));


            }
        }
        );

}
```

My "Remove" jButton:

```
 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable_products.getModel();
            try{

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectephone","root","");
            String sql= "delete from mycart(Model,Price,Stock) values(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            pst.setString(1, a);
            pst.setString(2,Price);
            pst.setString(3, Stock);
            model.removeRow(jTable_products.getSelectedRow());
            a="";
            Price="";
            Stock="";

            pst.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
             repaint();
        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectephone","root","");
            String sql = "SELECT * from mycart";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            jTable_products.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fails to display"+e);
        }
    }
```

"Clear" jButton:

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_products.getModel();

```
    while(model.getRowCount() > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount();i++){
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
xception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:734)
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:477)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2717)
    at Genos.Main$1.valueChanged(Main.java:32)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:677)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableRowsDeleted(JTable.java:4509)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4412)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:463)
    at Genos.Main.jButton7ActionPerformed(Main.java:377)
    at Genos.Main.access$700(Main.java:19)
    at Genos.Main$8.actionPerformed(Main.java:155)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: @Chester Vacalares Exactly which line is causing the error?

Comment: `int selectedRow = jTable_products.getSelectedRow();` - this is returning -1, you have no selected row.

Comment: Im sorry but i cant seem to find that code in mine.

Comment: Oh, found it. Sorry.

Comment: Should i do it like this? int selectedRow = jTable_products.getSelectedRow(jTable_products);

Comment: @ChesterVacalares do you select a row before this line execute ? plz provide the strack trace .very incomplete question

Comment: @user3437460 I cant say. It does not show any error in my arguments.

Comment: @Fast Snail Yes sir, you have to first select a row before you can "remove".

Comment: @ChesterVacalares is there any reason you to not to post the complete  error here ?

Comment: The Exception e Error? or the ones w/ the red lines? Im sorry but i don't know much about technicalities when posting about errors.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: Ok, when i run my program and clicked the "Remove" jButton it does not show the Stack Trace. But when i have click the "Clear" button in my jFrame it shows the Stack Trace(Edited above)

Answer (score 1):

> But when i have click the "Clear" button in my jFrame it shows the Stack Trace

The code works fine for me although the code is very confusing and way more complex than it needs to be.

The DefaultTableModel provides a method that allows you do delete all the rows:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

No need for the while loop of if loop.

Comment: That is really helpful. Thanks. But what i need from the "Clear" and the "Remove" button is to edit the Data Table itself, not the jTable. So the purpose of "Clear" is to clear out the list stored in my Data Table.

Comment: @ChesterVacalares, I have no idea what the "Data Table" is?. When using Swing your should only ever make changes the to the TableModel. The TableModel will then notify the table to repaint itself. That is why the removeRow() and setRowCount() methods works on the DefaultTableModel. So the solution I suggest is working on the data, not the table directly.